# HTML How to auto select a check box?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, html-table

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table border = 0 cellpadding=5 >

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="all_sizes" value="All">All<br></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="10mm" value="10mm">10mm<br></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="20mm" value="20mm">20mm<br></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="30mm" value="30mm">30mm<br></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="40mm" value="40mm">40mm<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How would we go about selecting the first check box by default?

Comment: Add **checked = "checked"** to the input you want selected.

Comment: i think its just the keyword checked

Comment: For XHTML the recommended way is as described. Check HTML manual and W3C to confirm.

Comment: The markup posted isn’t XHTML, so it’s logical to use just the simple keyword attribute `checked`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="all_sizes" value="All">All<br></td>
```

to this (add the keyword 'checked'):

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="all_sizes" value="All" checked>All<br></td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you've fetched your data from mysql using `mysqli_query()`

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="all_sizes" value="All" <?php if($data['col_name'] == 'val') { echo 'checked'; }?>>Value</td>
```