# click a button on a web site automatically with javascript

Tags: javascript

I modify a code like that, for click a checkbox.

Such as,
[image: My problem is]

Is there a any problem about button name or id. I could see just name and class. Is this a problem for work?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="My_Link" class="wp_textBox"><button>Giris</button></a>
</body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var chkA5 = "button" class=formCheckBox type=checkbox value=ON name=chkA5
         window.onload = function() {
          document.getElementById("chkA5").checked = true
        });
        }
        </script>

</html>
```

I copied all chechbox button properties on web site (F12 + Slect Element + click to check box) and pasted in my script. But I really confused, when I write a code in script, describing works for new things which I add or create. On this web site which I want to click a chechbox on has already buttons and text/check box. How can I create a connect with each other my scrips and web site.

In brief; I couldn't connect my scripts to web site's button and because of that I couldn't do  any operation. Am I right?

How can I solve this problem? On picture which I shared, there are  some code marked in a red square. This code works for desciribe some element in my scribs?

When we use `document.get.ElementById().checked =true`, on web site's element properties's has not a id? It has name and class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML How to auto select a check box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427966/html-how-to-auto-select-a-check-box)

Comment: The code looks incomplete.

Comment: @JonyD I saw this tag but ,It is in the same html, I want to click a checkbox on a web site  that  Already works. This kind of method work for your own check box which created on your html. I don't create a check box because of that how can I interfere on input line. I  need to interfere web site's checkbox

Comment: @Svek 
 
I saw that after I shared it was id and I changed for try after that I forget. But still don't work even I changed to as "id" again.

Comment: what is `var chkA5 = "button" class=formCheckBox type=checkbox value=ON name=chkA5` doing in the `<script>` block? You might want to review your code...

Comment: I am asking that, I copied that on web site, please read my text under the tag. Already I am asking that, How can connect my codes to buttons with code.

Comment: @Svek iy doesnt matter like that too;

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="My_Link" class="wp_textBox"><button>Giris</button></a>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var chkA5 = "checkbox" 
   window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("chkA5").checked = true
  });
  }
  </script>

</html>

Comment: @MustafaCoskun I am unable to replicate your issue, I updated my answer to provide you with a complete html sample. Could you please provide the full code, you are trying to update something on THIS window and and not some other window, correct?

Comment: @Svek actually second ansver is the full code, I tought if I complate checkbox I can go ahead for anothers with this way.

The code is full but you can't connect because of domain ( and username and password).

I will try that way for another web site, we can talk on it.

Comment: @MustafaCoskun your question is quite different from what you're expecting an answer for... You're looking to use Javascript to access another page's elements. I suggest you start with something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899047/how-to-use-javascript-to-access-another-pages-elements

Comment: @Svek Thank you. I am on searching.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1: `getElementById` should be `getElementByName`

Based on your screenshot, the input item you are trying to reference is:

> ```
> <input name="chkA5" class="formCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="ON"></input>
> ```

and you are trying to `getElementById()`

> ```
> document.getElementById("chkA5").checked = true
> ```

However, there is no id declared, so you will have to get the item by the name, using `getElementByName()`:

```
document.getElementsByName("chkA5")[0].checked = true;
```

---

### Problem 2: Your javascript has errors

This line will cause your script block fail:

> ```
> var chkA5 = "button" class=formCheckBox type=checkbox value=ON name=chkA5
> ```

If you require a complete code sample, here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="chkA5" class="formCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="ON"></input>
</body>
<script>
    (function() {
        document.getElementsByName("chkA5")[0].checked = true;
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

*Note: Make sure that the `script` block is at the end of your html, like in your example code provided.*

Comment: when I tried ;

<input name="chkA5" class="formCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="ON"></input>

that's mean is creating new checkbox.. I need to interfere a checkbox on web site. Already open and using web site.

Comment: @MustafaCoskun I think you are confused with my answer. Try replacing the last code block of my answer with yours.